# Статистика под заголовком

Tags: поддержка, дизайн

1. Зачем она там? Вроде очевидно побочная информация, которой не место на видном месте.
2. Как надо догадаться, что среднее значение - это ссылка?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Для любопытных? Мне не мешает, даже интересно

Comment: @avp я вот всё привыкнуть не могу =/

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, эту информацию перенесли из правой части (рядом с "важное"), чтобы в случае адаптивного дизайна (когда табличное представление страницы вырождается в один столбец) на устройствах с портретной ориентацией она отображалась рядом с вопросом, а не где-то внизу страницы.

С точки зрения ссылок, кажется, всё осталось по-прежнему. Оно и раньше было кликабельно. Может, конечно, как-то стоит согласовать с дизайном подчеркнутых ссылок. Но это уже нюансы. Всё-таки далеко не все кликабельные тексты имеют подчеркивание.

Выглядит пока несколько кривенько на моём мобильном:

> [image: статистика под заголовком]

Comment: Мобильная версия в принципе не очень, учитывая, что много страниц всё ещё в фул версии открываются.

Comment: @Suvitruf в том то и дело, что это не мобильная версия. Это адаптивная версия. Можно взять эту страницу и браузерное окно сузить до достижения точно такого же результата.

Comment: Раньше Шог отвечал на подобное, что это "старое наследие". Тут же, как погляжу, уже флексы используют, но всё равно криво :D

Comment: @Suvitruf "старое наследие", которое порождает кривизну на экране?

Comment: Ну типо "это старый код/вёрстка, мы это когда-нибудь поправим". Ага, поправили)

Comment: @Suvitruf наверное, он подразумевал "это старый код, мы его когда-нибудь используем ещё раз" :)